# ADFS with Group Policy from AD

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, adfs

My question:

Is it possible to enforce Group Policy into Active Directory Federation Service?

I have ADFS, Web application proxy and a web server. I wish to configure it so that a user who logs  into the ADFS via the web page can be enforced with a group policy, such as change the user account password when first login, change password after 90 days.

Is this implementation possible?

Comment: No. Those settings are only enforced by policies that are in the scope of domain controllers where the accounts reside.

Comment: I see. May I ask you whether is there such configuration (GPO, account policy) in the ADFS?

Comment: Are these external users or internal domain-joined users? Internal users will be forced to do this when they login to their desktop.

Comment: @nzpcmad, they are external users.

Comment: Right, so they are not domain-joined - see the first comment.